# Rcpp minimum memory allocation

Tags: r, memory, rcpp

I noticed that calling Rcpp functions requires a minimum amount of allocation per call. Is this something that is unavoidable even with simple functions?

For example, calling a simple Rcpp function that returns the integer 1, seems to need ~ 2.5KB of memory.

```r
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction("
  int one(){
  return 1;
  }
")

library(bench)

mark(one())
#> # A tibble: 1 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 one()         700ns    1.1µs   419263.    2.49KB        0
mark(one())
#> # A tibble: 1 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 one()         800ns    1.3µs   402156.    2.49KB        0
```

Repeatedly calling this quickly adds up the memory allocation.

```
replicate_one <- function(){
  for (i in 1:10^4){
    one()
  }
}

mark(replicate_one())
#> # A tibble: 1 × 6
#>   expression           min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 replicate_one()   11.9ms   15.1ms      65.9    24.4MB     57.7
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

My question is: is this perhaps a false positive and due to some inner quirks of R and if not, is there a way to avoid this minimal allocation when using simple Rcpp functions?

Appreciate it's possible I may have entirely missed the point of Rcpp and that this is actually expected behaviour.

In any case I'm keen to learn about best practices regarding memory management.

Comment: That’s probably due to the `RNGScope` object. You can disable that if you don’t need random numbers (use `[[Rcpp::export(rng = false)]]`).

Comment: Wow thanks! Just tried that and it worked. Is there a way to be certain that my code doesn't make use of random number generaton?

Comment: @NicChr Run it several times and check if results are identical?

Comment: @NicChr most times whem a programmer creates code he/she is aware of whether to algorithm used is deterministic or stochastic <grin>.  Kidding aside, because there is in general a small amount of extra overhead in calling C(++) from R you want to minimize those calls and, say, call one 'glue code function' which may call C(++) worker functions directly / repeatedly.  All this was discussed quite extensively in the context of the classsic Fibnacci example about a decade ago so if you search carefully you should find it.